# How to plug back instance index to the instance generator

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I can't find a solution on how to randomize the instance's parameters per instance.
Please note, this question is theoretical, I'm not looking for a solution for this individual problem on the screenshot, instead I'd like to change my instance generator's parameters per instance. (The instance generator in this example is the Grid, the Set Position and the Random value nodes)
Blender throws an error if I try to plug my instance index back to the random Value's ID input. So, the result here would be different randomness for every instance.

[image: just an example]

Comment: This question was asked multiple times. The simple answer is: you cannot. You have to solve it different.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean goldfishs or your answer? 